# Can't install autotest 4.4.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, autotest

I'm using RVM, and when I attempt to install autotest with:

```
rvmsudo gem install autotest
```

and get

> Fetching: autotest-4.4.6.gem (100%)
>   Successfully installed autotest-4.4.6
>   1 gem installed
>   Installing ri documentation for autotest-4.4.6...
>   file 'lib' not found
>   Installing RDoc documentation for autotest-4.4.6...
>   file 'lib' not found

No executable autotest file is installed, and `find ~/.rvm -name autotest` returns no results in any autotest folder; so it doesn't look like it installed at all.  Anyone have any clues how to get it to work?

Comment: rvmsudo gem install autotest --no-ri --no-rdoc

Answer (score 0):

Try this line

```
rvmsudo gem install autotest --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Answer (score 0):

when I bundle install autotest 4.4.6 it install Zentest